# How to display new select values based on already selected value without submitting im HTML

Tags: javascript, html, forms, submit

I have a form with 2 select boxes and text boxes, my aim is to display some values from my database based on the value selected from the previous select box,
but I need to do it inside the same page without submitting the form.

```html
 <form id="form5" method="post" action="hello.php"><div id="right">
<fieldset>
<input type="hidden" name="hid2" value="hid2"><br>
<h3>
<br><br>
<label for="loca">Select Location:</label>
  <select name="locat" id="locat">
    <option value="">Select Location:</option>
    <option value="1">ALAPPUZHA</option>
    <option value="2 ">CALICUT</option>
    <option value="3">COCHIN</option>
    <option value="4">KANNUR</option>
    <option value="5">KOLLAM</option>
    <option value="6 ">KOTTAYAM</option>
    <option value="7">MALAPPURAMM</option>
    <option value="8">PALAKKAD</option>
    <option value="9">PATHANAMTHITTA</option>
    <option value="10">THRISSUR</option>
    <option value="11">TRIVANDRUM</option>
  </select><br>
<select name="place" id="place">
    <option value="">Select Location:</option>
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value=""></option>
</select>
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
    <br></h3>
    </fieldset>
</form></div>
```

Comment: Please include what you have already tried. SO isn't a coding service.

Comment: Why not use JQUERY and AJAX?

Comment: Am not familiar with that

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend getting the two database queries you need on load, and displaying their results based on the selection. So your target would be to load the database entries on page load, rather than on html change and then display them how you see fit.

Comment: so can i use a sql select query with where clause  there after the first select box which use the vlue selected in the first select box?

Comment: Normally if you want to make a dropdown based on selection consisting of SQL results, what you need to do is preload ALL SQL queries into different Select Statements and then use Javascript, css, jquery to show/hide the select boxes that are required and hide the oens that are not.